# How can I get Swift to continuously update the speed

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I've been learning to use swift to make an app and wanted to make a basic app that tells you your speed. However I can not figure out how to get it to update the speed, at the moment it only gives me the initial speed and never updates the label with the current speed. Here is the code I have to far:

```
@IBOutlet var speedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var countLabel: UILabel!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    speed = locationManager.location!.speed

    if speed < 0 {
        speedLabel.text = "No movement registered"
    }
    else {
        speedLabel.text = "\(speed)"
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegate's method https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
       didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let speed = manager.location?.speed else { return }
        speedLabel.text = speed < 0 ? "No movement registered" : "\(speed)"
}
```

Also you are calling this twice `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`, so you can remove one call